# python zipfile directory gets copied too

Tags: python, zip

I'm experimenting with the zipfile module of python
the code i currently use is this:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile("jar/algorithms.jar", "w")
z.write('directory/QuickSort.class')
```

The problem is that my file is added to the jar as following:

algorithms.jar>directory>QuickSort.class

What I want is:
algorithms.jar>QuickSort.class

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the arcname parameter - see http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

```
z.write("directory/QuickSort.class","QuickSort.class")
```

Comment: Ok that seems to work. Still got a small problem here though:

I use a QInputDialog to get the path to the .class file

if this is the path'H:/Documenten van Walter/Documenten/Python/PyComplexity/src/jar/someclass.class'

how can i get the arcname out of it then?

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the name you want the file to have in the archive as the second parameter to `write` like this:

```
In [39]: z = zipfile.ZipFile("jar/algorithms.jar", "w")

In [40]: z.printdir()
File Name                                             Modified             Size

In [41]: z.write("directory/QuickSort.class", "QuickSort.class")

In [42]: z.printdir()
File Name                                             Modified             Size
QuickSort.class                                2011-08-10 15:26:47            0

In [43]: z.close()
```

Also see the [zipfile documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: Ok that seems to work. Still got a small problem here though: I use a QInputDialog to get the path to the .class file if this is the path'H:/Documenten van Walter/Documenten/Python/PyComplexity/src/jar/someclass.class' how can i get the arcname out of it then?

Comment: If path is set to 'H:/Documenten van Walter/Documenten/Python/PyComplexity/src/jar/someclass.class' then you could use os.path's methods like this: `arcname = os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(path))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. This will create a zipped archive of a folder in that same folder and remove the directory structure from the zipped output file.

```
import os
import zipfile
mydir = r'c:\temp\filestozip' #all the files in this directory will be archived
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(mydir + '\\myzipfile.zip', "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.zip'): #
            zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename),arcname=filename)
zf.close()
```